# Why is Flutter open_file not opening files on android device?

Tags: android, flutter, file, dart

I'm working on a mobile Flutter app. I need to show some files in the app, but on iOS the files are opening correctly and on Android it won't. Does anyone know what's the problem?

here is my code:

```
if (await File("$dir/" + documentName).exists()) {
    
        // if true then open file
        OpenFile.open("$dir/" + documentName).whenComplete(() => Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => documents_page(),
            transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
          ),
        ));
      }
```

I don't get any errors as well..

Comment: What exactly are you seeing in the logs? Are you sure the path to files is correct?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, when I open the file there are no errors at all in the console. And the weird part is that I can open the files on iOS, but not on Android..

Comment: @tomerPacific For the file path I use path_provider... I Stored the incoming files in the directory: getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path

Comment: Still, are you sure the path you are giving is the correct path to the file? Have you debugged your code and seen that the if condition evaluates to true?

Comment: Even if I check if the file exists it returns true.